# Tensorflow dataset causes a memory leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm creating a dataset for my xception model training, I'm doing it like this:

```
def load_dataset(height: int, width: int, path: str, kind: str, batch_size=32) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    directory = os.path.join(path, kind)

    return keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        directory=directory,
        labels='inferred',
        label_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        image_size=(height, width))


def load_rebalanced_dataset(
        height: int,
        width: int,
        path: str,
        kind: str,
        batch_size=32,
        do_repeat: bool = True) -> (tf.data.Dataset, list[str]):
    dataset = load_dataset(height, width, path, kind, batch_size)
    classes = dataset.class_names
    num_classes = len(classes)
    class_datasets = []

    for class_idx in range(num_classes):
        class_datasets.append(dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, axis=-1), class_idx))))

    balanced_ds = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets(class_datasets, [1.0 / num_classes] * num_classes)

    if do_repeat:
        balanced_ds = balanced_ds.repeat()

    balanced_ds = balanced_ds.cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return balanced_ds, classes
```

Something in the `load_rebalanced_dataset` function is making tf fill up all the available RAM memory (64 GB). It trains w/o problems for the first ~17 epochs until I get an OOM error. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I have the same problem. I build a dataset pipeline to read many csv and feed my bodel but the shared memory build up until crash. Did you find a solution??

Comment: Sadly, no. I switched to another way of doing the same - basically just restarting the jupyter kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem too,and finaly find something who is working in may case, wich it will help you too.

Try removing ".cache()
you:

```
balanced_ds = balanced_ds.cache().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

solution:

```
balanced_ds = balanced_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

As I understand, cache() build up all your data in memory on the first epochs to be faster on the nexts epoch.
Why it work on first epoch and crash later, mistery... probably the processing add some memory build up and data use almost your capacity... I'm not sure but give it a try, it work for me.

Comment: It didn't work in my case :(